# jquery offset not working occasionally with resize event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a footer which needs to be absolutely positioned at the bottom of the window if the height of cards is less than that of the window. In case if the window is resized to an extent where height of cards is greater than the window height then the footer should get stacked below the card. The issue arises when I resize the window to a height which is lesser than the cards height, the `if` condition sometimes return true and sometimes false but not always true which is expected.

```
$(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
       if($('footer').offset().top > $('.cards').outerHeight()) {
            $('footer').css({
                 position: 'absolute'
             });
          console.log('true');
        } else {
            $('footer').css({
                 position: 'static'
             });
          console.log('false');
        } 
    });
});
```

Comment: `Sometimes return false`. Well, your condition is not reached, false is good result. What's the problem?

Comment: The condition is `if the offset of the footer is greater than the total height of cards return true`. If not returns false :)